# Getting <li> value with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

below I have a selectable dropdown list. I need to pass the choosed value to ng-model directive:

```
ng-model="$root.specCategory_search"
```

But its not working in my example. How can I do it?
Previously I used it with select option and its working fine with ng-model directive. For that I used the value="" attribute within option tag.

**HTML Dropdown**

```
<div class="btn-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   <span ng-model="$root.specCategory_search" data-bind="label">Select One</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
      <li><a href="#">First item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">This is a longer item that will not fit properly</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-input {
   display: block;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control {
    text-align: left;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control span:first-child {
   left: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   right: 25px;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control .caret {
   margin-top: -1px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 10px;
   top: 50%;
```

**JS**

```
      $( document.body ).on( 'click', '.dropdown-menu li', function( event ) {

      var $target = $( event.currentTarget );

      $target.closest( '.btn-group' )
         .find( '[data-bind="label"]' ).text( $target.text() )
            .end()
         .children( '.dropdown-toggle' ).dropdown( 'toggle' );

      return false;

   });
```

Comment: why you go with `<ul>` and `<li>` when `<select>` is working fine?

Comment: Actually the design is more nesty for me.

Comment: you can change design according select tag

Comment: did you had a look at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution in your case would be to create a directive that will attach the an event listener on click and extract the required value.
Then using the isolate scope you can bind the value of the dropdown and use it where you need it in your app.

Here is a starting point that you can further develop:

```js
(function() {
 
  var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);
  
  app.directive('ddMenu', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        ddMenu: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element) {
        // set the initial value
        var $el = $(element);
        scope.ddMenu = $el.find('li:first').text();
        
        // listen for changes
        $el.on('click', 'li', function() {
          scope.ddMenu = $(this).text();
          scope.$apply(); 
        });
      }
    };
  });
  
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div ng-app="demoApp">

<div class="btn-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   <span ng-bind="ddValue">Select One</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" dd-menu="ddValue" role="menu" >
      <li><a href="#">First item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">This is a longer item that will not fit properly</a></li>
   </ul>
  
  Val: {{ddValue}}
</div>
```

Comment: Would you mind to change your code in this way to be cleaner to use. 
dd-menu value="ddValue" => dd-menu="ddValue"

Comment: @DragonKnight I have updated it, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Saved my hours! Great hack! Ty.